# Haskell : words, unwords delimiter

Tags: haskell

Is there any way I can provide a delimiter to `words` and `unwords` in haskell, to make it similar to split and join in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but they're really just (optimized versions of) applications of [`Data.List.break`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-List.html#v%3abreak) and [`Data.List.intersperse`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-List.html#v%3aintersperse), respectively.

```
pythonicSplit      :: String -> Char -> [String]
pythonicSplit "" _ =  []
pythonicSplit s  c =  let (r,rs) = break (== c) s
                       in r : pythonicSplit rs c

pythonicJoin       :: [String] -> Char -> String
pythonicJoin  ss c =  intersperse c ss -- or: flip intersperse
```

Comment: I'll leave versions that split on a string or any of several characters as exercises for the reader, if only because it's past my bedtime. :) But I will note that all the tools you need are in `Data.List` and that the multi-character join is already there just as the single-character join was.

Comment: See also `intercalate` for a multi-character delimiter instead of `intersperse`.

Comment: your `pythonicSplit` is incorrect. after the first word, it generates an infinite list of empty strings

Comment: intersperse returns a list. To join to a string, try this: `joinOn str l = foldl1 (\acc x -> acc ++ str ++ x) l`

Comment: The following returns a string (you don't need a lamba to apply ++, just curry it): pythonicJoin c ss = foldl (++) "" (intersperse c ss)

Answer (score 10):

Please also have a look at the genial package *split*. It provides a module [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.3/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) for all sort of splitting.

Answer (score 1):

[Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1) has [splitOn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:splitOn) & [intercalate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:intercalate) which is equivalent to Python's `split` & `join`.