# Haskell write a function to perform input function on list

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to write a function which performs a input function `f` on input list `ls` `[l1, l2, ..., ln]` and output a string    `"[" ++ (f l1) ++ "," ++ (f l2) ++ "," ++ ... ++ (f ln) ++ "]"`

```
flist :: (a -> String) -> [a] -> String
flist f ls =
```

for example:

```
>flist show [1, 2, 3]
```

would output `"[1, 2, 3]"`

```
>flist (fun x -> x) ["dog"]
```

would output `"[dog]"`

I tried to use foldl'

```
flist f ls = "[" ++ (foldl' (++) f "," ls) ++ "]"
```

which doesn't seems to be working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

1. Produce `[f x1,...,f xn]` first, applying `f` to every member.
2. Then, write a function that takes `[y1,...,yn]` and `w` and produces an interleaving `[y1,w,y2,w,...,yn]`. This can be done by recursion. (There's also a library function for that, but it's not important.)
3. Compose both, to obtain `[f x1, ",", ...]` and then concatenate the result.
4. Add brackets to the resulting string.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
import Data.List

flist f list = "[" ++ (intercalate "," $ map f list) ++ "]"
```

`intercalate` puts Strings in between of other Strings, it is (in this case) [a slightly configurable version of `unwords`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521560/haskell-words-unwords-delimiter).